# Phase shift of non-isosceles triangle wave

Tags: wave

I am researching a dynamic system. It takes in a sine wave `A*sin(2*pi*f*t) + D` and outputs a non-isosceles triangle wave. Let's call input signal SP and output signal PV. I want to create amplitude and phase characteristics of this system. I have taken measurements of SP and PV for different `f`s. Amplitude `A` was the same for every measurement. Now, calculating amplification of the system is easy (using Matlab notation: [range](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/range.html)):

`range(PV) / range(SP)`

But I have a problem with calculating phase shift. I have came up with a following algorithm, but I think it is not universal:

```matlab
% t is the time vector
dt = t(2) - t(1);

% SP and PV are read from file earlier
% here they are centered around 0
PV = centerSignal(PV);
SP = centerSignal(SP);

% T is the period of the signals derived from their frequency f
T = 1/f; % f ranges from 0.1 Hz to 10 Hz
%  I specify MinPeakDistance to ignore possible errors in data
peakDistance = round(0.5 * T / dt);
% find positive and negative peak's locations in SP and PV
[~,posPeaksPV] = findpeaks( PV + abs(PV),"MinPeakDistance",peakDistance);
[~,posPeaksSP] = findpeaks( SP + abs(SP),"MinPeakDistance",peakDistance);
[~,negPeaksPV] = findpeaks(-PV + abs(PV),"MinPeakDistance",peakDistance);
[~,negPeaksSP] = findpeaks(-SP + abs(SP),"MinPeakDistance",peakDistance);

% select only those peaks of PV that are after first peak of SP
posPeaksPV = posPeaksPV(posPeaksPV > posPeaksSP(1));
negPeaksPV = negPeaksPV(negPeaksPV > negPeaksSP(1));

% make peaks array the size of the smaller array
lenPos = min([length(posPeaksPV) length(posPeaksSP)]);
lenNeg = min([length(negPeaksPV) length(negPeaksSP)]);
posPeaksPV = posPeaksPV(1:lenPos);
posPeaksSP = posPeaksSP(1:lenPos);
negPeaksPV = negPeaksPV(1:lenNeg);
negPeaksSP = negPeaksSP(1:lenNeg);

% calculate phase shift
posPhaseShift = mean(t(posPeaksSP) - t(posPeaksPV));
negPhaseShift = mean(t(negPeaksSP) - t(negPeaksPV));
phaseShift = mean([posPhaseShift negPhaseShift]) * (360 / T)

function sigOut = centerSignal(sigIn)
minSig = min(sigIn);
maxSig = max(sigIn);
sigOut = sigIn - ((maxSig - minSig)/2 + minSig);
end
```

Matlab reference: [findpeaks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html)

I have made interactive version of this algorithm (and sort of my data) on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bnen9chrlo). The position I left the moveable points of triangle signal in, imitates this one sample below I've been analysing while trying to come up with the algorithm:

[image: Sample signals of frequency 1.8 Hz]

The calculation of amplification and phase shift on Desmos are analogical to those done by Matlab code above.

The one problem I've discovered while playing with visualisation on Desmos was that if you put one point on the peak of the sine wave and only move the other one the phase shift changes which seem kind of wrong.

Summarizing: **Is there a standard way of determining a phase shift between a sine wave and a non-isosceles triangle wave?**

Edit: By "phase shift" I mean how much is one signal shifted in time in respect to other signal. For sinusoids its easy: signals have the same phase when their peaks and valleys occur at the same time. But for non-isosceles triangle wave its not quite straightforward.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  What do you mean by "phase shift" in this instance? Usually, phase is compared between two sinusoids. I'm not sure I have a clear definition in my head of the phase of a non-isoceles triangle wave.  Can you edit your post to explain that definition?

Comment: I have edited the post, but I don't have **clear** definition of "the phase of a non-isosceles triangle wave". It is my first time when dealing with such a signal and I thought maybe there are some standard ways of checking the phase of such signal. Googling the problem didn't yield any helpful results either.

Comment: the plotted values for SP do not match the formula given.,

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've added `+ D` to the formula to account for the DC offset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a standard way of determining a phase shift between a sine wave and a non-isosceles triangle wave?

Not really. The operation you describe is highly non-linear so the concept of a transfer function doesn't apply.

Probably the best you can do here is to define the phase shift in terms of the fundamental. The triangle output can be represented as a Fourier Series with the same fundamental frequency as the input. You could define the shift as the phase difference between the input and the fundamental of the triangle. Each of the harmonics of the triangle also have a phase associated with them but there is no "one size fits all" way of defining a phase reference for them. Even if you did: they'd be all different numbers.

Whether any of this useful or not depends on what exactly your application or requirements are.

Comment: So you suggest: take Fourier transform of both signals, from that get phase (of both signals) of fundamental frequency of the input signal and subtract one phase from the other?

Comment: Yep. This is ONE way of doing this. Whether this is a GOOD way of doing it really depends on what you specifically planning to do with the result. There are OTHER ways that will give you different answers. There is no single "right" way.

Comment: I've tried this approach and it gave me OK-ish results for my purpose of documenting the system for university project. So I'm marking your answer as a correct one. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Remove any offset from the triangle so that its mean is zero, then:

Multiply the triangle by $\sin$ and $\cos$ of the original wave frequency,calculate the mean values of each function product then and use ATAN2() to get the phase angle.

Or you could do a Fourrier transform and get the phase difference of from that (this is basically doing the same thing).

---

EDIT: Attached is a quick attempt to implement this suggestion. It seems to work OK, but you'll have to be careful of "phase" definitions.

---

#### Code Below

```matlab
% 91541
fs = 1000;
N = 1024;
omega = 2*pi*12.345678/fs;

period = 2*pi/omega;
periods = N/period;

T = periods*2*pi/omega;
t = 0:1/fs:(T-1/fs);

x = cos(omega*t - phi);
y = -sawtooth(omega*t-phi*2, 0.5);
plot(t, x)
hold on;

plot(t, y);
hold off;

C = cos(omega*t);
S = sin(omega*t);

phi/pi*180
phi_hat = atan2(mean(S.*x), mean(C.*x))/pi*180
tri_hat = atan2(mean(S.*y), mean(C.*y))/pi*180
```

Comment: Nice idea!  I hope you don't mind me adding an attempt at matlab code to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a standard way of determining a phase shift between a sine wave and a non-isosceles triangle wave?

No.

Why, you ask?

Because phase shift is a concept that comes from linear time-invariant signal analysis, and you simply don't get a triangle-wave signal -- isosceles or not -- from a sine wave with a linear, time-invariant system*.

For your phase shift to have any meaning, you'll first have to think about what your output waveform means in some quasi-linear system way.  Then you'll have to express that so that you (and, hopefully, others) understand it.  Then you'll have to test that description to make sure that it's useful.  Presumably, at some point in this process you'll define how to calculate the phase of your output in this context you've invented.

---

* and while there may be a linear time-*varying* system that will do this, I can't think of one off hand, and there's certainly no general system that would do it.